# How Can I access a function through props in another component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have two components Checkout.js and Checklist.js
I have managed to pass data down form checklist to checkout but I have a function to remove item from checkout but i dont know how to access it through props.
How can i Access the removeFood function inside checkout component
My Checklist .js

```
import React from 'react';
import './componentStyle.css';
function CheckList(props) {
    return <div className="checkoutList">
        <form>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="name">Food</label>
                <input type="text" readOnly id='name' value={props.food}></input>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="price">Price</label>
                <input type="number" readOnly id='price' value={props.price}></input>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="quantity">Quantity</label>
                <input type="number" readOnly id='quantity' value={props.quant}></input>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="total">Total</label>
                <input type="number" readOnly id='total' value={props.total}></input>
            </div>
            
        </form>
        <button style={{
            cursor:"pointer"
        }} onClick={}  type='button'>Remove</button>
    </div>;
}

export default CheckList;
```

My checkout.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import CheckList from '../components/CheckList';
import Data from '../data.json';
import OrderBtn from '../components/TrayOrderBtn';

function Checkout(props) {
  const foodItem = (
    Data.myTray.map((item) => <CheckList id={item[Math.random().toString().slice(2)]} key={item.id} food={item['food']} price={item['price']} quant={item['quantity']} />)
  )

 
  var [widget, setWidget] = useState(Data.myTray);

  const removeFood=(item)=> {
    widget.filter((w) => w.id !== item.id)
    
  }
  console.log(widget)
 

  useEffect(() => {
    setWidget(Data.myTray)
  },[widget])
  
  if (Data.myTray.length <= 0) {
    return <div>
      <h1>Add a Food Item to Your Tray</h1>
    </div>
  }else {
    return <div className="checkout">
      {widget.map(
        (item) => <CheckList  key={item.id} food={item['food']} price={item['price']} quant={item['quantity']} />
      )}
      <OrderBtn />
    </div>;
  }
  
}

export default Checkout;
```

Comment: just pass it as prop of `CheckList` in the same way as the other props

Comment: I get an error props.function is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Take a look at the example below-**

Suppose you have a component Checkout and you want to pass your delete function to Checklist component so that you can apply a event listener in Checklist component.

```
Here we are passing our delete function as a prop to Checklist component
```

**Note: -This is just an example how you can implement.**

**See our Checkout Component**

```js
export default function Checkout(){

const handleDelete=(data)=>{
console.log(data);
}

return(
<Checklist handleDelete={handleDelete}/>
)

}
```

**See our Checklist Component**

```js
export default function Checklist(props){

return(
<button onclick={()=>props.handleDelete("your target id or anything")}>Delete</button>
)
}
```

Comment: I hope you have understood?

Comment: understood let me try it out

Comment: If this is the delete function   const handleDelete=(item)=> {
    widget.filter((w) => w.id !== item.id)
    
  }
  console.log(widget)  How do i add the target on the other end

Comment: can you explain little bit more I couldn't understand and filter method returns an array so you should store it into a variable something like - const items= widget.filter((w) => w.id !== item.id)

Comment: Check my code up there, the mapped widget is an array

Comment: if you take a look at your removeFood function, you are filtering your widget array right? then you need to know filter method returns an array , if you are not storing your filtered item then what is the advantage of removeFood function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal reproducible example. The `add` and `remove` functions are defined in `App` and passed down to children components `Products` and `Checkout` accordingly. Run the code and click some <kbd>carrot</kbd> and <kbd>banana</kbd> into your cart. Then click <kbd>❌</kbd> to remove some.

```js
function App() {
  const [cart, setCart] = React.useState([])
  const add = item => e =>
    setCart([...cart, item])
  const remove = index => e =>
    setCart([...cart.slice(0, index), ...cart.slice(index+1)])
  return <div>
    <Products add={add} />
    <Checkout cart={cart} remove={remove} />
  </div>
}

function Products({ add }) {
  const PRODUCTS = ["apple", "banana", "carrot"]
  return <div className="products">
    {PRODUCTS.map((p, key) =>
      <button key={key} type="button" onClick={add(p)} children={p} />
    )}
  </div>
}

function Checkout({ cart, remove }) {
  return <div className="checkout">
    {cart.map((c, key) =>
      <div>{c} <button type="button" onClick={remove(key)} children="❌"/></div>
    )}
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
.products, .checkout { display: flex; flex-direction: flex-row; flex-wrap: wrap; }
.products > button { padding: 0.5rem; margin: 0.5rem; }
.checkout > div { background-color: #CDECFF; padding: 0.5rem; margin: 0.5rem; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

See [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) in the React Docs for additional examples.